# Experiencing a error "Node interpretor: (Project Node no executable found in %PATH%)"

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgrhZ.png)
In Intellij-IDEA Ultimate, while executing a basic core Java script program, I am getting the above error. I searched on Google to find a solution but didn't find any suitable solutions for this. I only saw that you need to install node.js on your PC and set the path for it to execute. Do I need Node.js to execute normal Java script programs, or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes you need Node.js, as you found out in your research.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Node.js interpreter installed to be able to run JavaScript.
Please download it from https://nodejs.org/en/download and specify the path to Node.js executable in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js**. Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/developing-node-js-applications.html#ws_node_configure_local_node_interpreter.